# nth-child(even) for a css class only not all nodes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Trying to only color certain every other div of class `'story'`:

```
<div class="wrap-well">
    <div class="story">odd</div>
    <div class="story">even</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="story">odd</div>
    <div class="story">even</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="story">odd</div>
    <div class="story">even</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap-well div.story:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NF2dk/

But it seems that `'clearfix'` columns are also counted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Marcin and @Explosion Pills is absolutely right here, but as I inspected your DOM, you've a consistent pattern going on there, you can use Adjacent selector to achieve this rather than using `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`

```
.wrap-well div.story + div.story {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/NF2dk/2/)

This way, it will just do the job what you wanted to achieve, also it's much more compatible compared to `nth` pseudos

Answer (score 3):

`nth-child` does not work with the selector, but the element.  It selects each even div regardless of the composition of the selector.

You can use `nth-of-type` to only select `<div>` elements and use another element such as `<br>` for the clearfix.

http://jsfiddle.net/NF2dk/1/

Comment: `<br>` is probably not the best candidate since it imposes extra whitespace, as seen in your updated fiddle. Perhaps a `<span>` with `display: block` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing like `nth-of-class()` selector.**

The closest you can get is `nth-of-type()`. But it will look at the element tag, not `class` assigned to the element.